# Cannot get Weather widget to display on lock screen (WIndows 10)

Tags: windows-10, lock-screen, weather

I am currently running a Windows 10 Pro desktop machine (21H1, build 19043.1288) and cannot get the Weather app to display detailed status info on the lock screen.  I have configured the appropriate settings in Settings > Personalisation > Lock Screen as follows:

[image]

I have set the default location in the Weather app's settings to my current location.  The Weather app has no problem displaying the correct weather details when I launch it once logged in.

Can anyone shed some light on this?  Are there any other settings I can check?  I also find it suspicious that most apps in the lock screen list have grey icons, almost like they are disabled.  Could this be a hint at some problem?

Comment: I am having the same issue. Interestingly enough, it was working fine up until about 10 minutes ago, except that it was showing the wrong city (but the right time zone). I finally decided to change this and launched (probably for the first time) the Weather app to change the default settings. After doing that the basic weather info no longer shows on my lock screen. My weather app icon is also greyed out in the lock screen options, but it was like that before I made my change as well. Do you have any update? Were you able to find a solution?

Comment: I would suggest to use System Restore (if enabled) to rollback to before this was done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this option no longer works following one of the latest updates of
Windows 10.

It is apparently easy to do in Windows 11. See
[How To Make Weather Appear On Lock Screen In Windows 11 [Tutorial]](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nNkhGu-N9Vg)

Answer (score 0):

Right click anywhere on the TASKBAR (not in windows logo)

Select 'News and Interests' and select 'Show icon and text'

Enjoy.

Comment: This made no difference.